# How do I Edit ext4 filesystem data file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mount, ext4

I have an ext4 filesystem data file `myfile.bin`

`file myfile.bin` gives

> Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=...... (needs journal recovery) (extents) (large files) (huge files)

I am able to mount this with `sudo mount -o loop myfile.bin ~/dir`, but it is read only.
Even when i do `sudo mount -o rw myfile.bin ~/dir` it is read only.

Is there any way i can edit the file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [debugfs](https://linux.die.net/man/8/debugfs) ext-file-system debugger to directly make changes. But you should have a good understanding about the internals of the filesystem if you plan to do so.

Even better, you can run `fsck` on it, which will recover the journal and remove the "needs journal recovery" flag, so you can mount it read-write.

If there's a valuable data on it that may get lost during a recovery, make a backup first.

Comment: Doesn't mounting the image r/w already perform journal recovery as normal operation? I don't exactly remember whether in ext2/3/4 it is fsck's job or the kernel's job...

Comment: @grawity: If it does that, why doesn't the attempt to mount it rw remove the "recover needed" flag?